# web page communicating with a wcf service

Tags: vb.net, wcf, service

I have an idea for a program that will run as an application (handling most of the work) on a singe computer but the main interface will be browser-based and accessible from any computer on the network. Like [sabNZB](http://sabnzbd.org/) or [vibestreamer](http://www.vibestreamer.com/), which have server apps with web-based UI's anyone can access.

So far I have a WCF service library in my server app (written in vb.net). How do I make the web page "talk" (send data) to the service? Do I need to use jscript or should I be using something else?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how your wcf endpoints is exposed. But in general a good solution could be to use ajax. Something like this (using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)):

```
var json = { "test": "test" }; 
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "YourWCF.svc/Method",
    data: json,
    processData: true,
    contentType: "application/json",
    timeout: 10000, 
    dataType: "json", 
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) { //Successfull callback
    }
});
```